# Why would is_int(sqrt(100)) return false

Tags: php, integer

Does anyone know why this always returns False?

```
is_int(sqrt(100))
```

and what syntax should i use to check is square root is an integer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check whether a `sqrt` is an integer, you can do:

```
$root = sqrt($val);

if((int) $root == $root)) {
    // root is integer
}
```

Comment: Comparing floating-point values to things with `==`? Naughty... Though, come to think of it, are there any whole-number floating point values for which this test would break?

Answer (score 10):

[`sqrt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php) function returns `float` value, not `int`.

Comment: Then wouldn't a float value equal to 10 be taken as an integer ?

Comment: @silkAdmin: Apparently not.  :P

Comment: Not exacly - `10` can still be `float` with `.0` at the end that is not echoed ;-) It is still treated by PHP engine as a `float`. If you wants to make it `int`, cast it by your own with `(int) sqrt(100)`.

Comment: @silkAdmin: Apparently not. `is_int(10.0)` returns `false`.

Comment: However if you want to check if `sqrt` result is `int`, do it with following test: `$sqrt = sqrt(100); if ( $sqrt == (int) $sqrt ) {}`

Comment: @silkAdmin: `is_int` is not `is_integral-looking_value_represented_as_any_numeric_type`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yeah, why not ? If we use `==` then `10.0 == 10` gives true. I bet you are thinking about `===` which will gives false because of checking variables type.

Comment: @hsz: No, I'm not. I'm thinking about checking floating-point values for direct equality being the most common programmer mistake. I'm sure the OP's input isn't _always_ `10.0`. Though actually I'm not sure whether it'll break _this_ test.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I guess that Op needs to filter out all `10.0`, `4.0`, `2.0` values, so my test will be good for it. If input will be `10.1` then `10.1 == (int) 10.1` => `10.1 == 10` will returns false.

Comment: @hsz: My point is... read up about floating-point inaccuracy. You could get false negatives with e.g. `10.0==10`. I think.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is in your definition of "integer". You're reading it as "a value with no non-zero fractional significant figures", whereas in `is_int` it just refers to a datatype, i.e. literally anything with type `int`.

That is, the floating-point value `10.0` is still a floating-point value, even though its mathematical value is equal to that of the integer `10`.

The result of `sqrt` is *never* an integer; however, you can check whether a floating-point value has any non-zero fractional significant figures by comparing it to one in which you deliberately took them all off.

A naive implementation:

```
$sqrt = sqrt(100);
if ($sqrt == (int)$sqrt) {
   // ...
}
```

However, of course you should never compare anything against a floating-point value with `==`; use your favourite floating-point equality mechanism to perform this test.

#### Update

Actually, I suppose the only values for which this comparison could potentially fail are fractional, in which case the test should fail anyway. So `==` might be sufficient.

Comment: Could fail for negative values such as sqrt(-100), but worth a +1 for being the most comprehensive answer to this question

Comment: @MarkBaker: `sqrt`'s argument must be positive.

Comment: If it isn't positive, you get a return that can be tested with is_nan()

Comment: @MarkBaker: (a) NaN `==` `(int)NaN` is going to yield `false` anyway, so that already negates your initial comment. (b) And I don't believe it's guaranteed that `sqrt(-100)` evaluates to `NaN`; I believe it's _only_ guaranteed to set `errno` to `EDOM`.

Comment: Yep, C99 `7.12.1/2` says it's implementation-defined.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit
`if ((string) $sqr == (string) floor($sqr))
{
 echo 'int';
}` Would that work, or is it too expensive?

Comment: @silkAdmin: It'd probably work. Whether it's "too expensive" for you depends on too many things; profile it!

Answer (score 2):

[`sqrt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php) returns a float, not an integer, therefore [`is_int`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) returns false.

Try use [`is_float`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) instead.

Comment: yeah but in that case it returns false all the time ?

Comment: Well, if you ask a `float` if it is an `integer` it will say no all the time! But there are ways to convert them, look at comment by @hsz in the other reply, he shows how it is done.

Comment: I don't see how `is_float(sqrt(x))` would ever be a useful thing to do. There's literally nothing that expression could evaluate to other than `true`.

Comment: It can be useful in certain situations, but I've used it rarely so far.

Answer (score 1):

is_int() refers to the **datatype** of the result, not to the value contained in that result. sqrt() **always** returns a result of datatype float, irrespective of the value

Comment: Sorry my question was not well formatted and derived topic though you were answering perfectly my initial query. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Data type of `sqrt(100) is float`. `is_int` checks for the data type not the `value`

Comment: This answer just copies the first two answers posted 10 minutes before yours and provides no information beyond theirs. If you like their answers, upvote them, rather than "me-too-ing"